# Populate TreeView TKinter Widget with parent and children nodes from a DB

Tags: python, tkinter, neo4j, treeview

my problem is: I am trying to populate the TreeView widget with data from DB, in my case Neo4j. I have a set of car brands and some car models of these brands, what I expect, should be something like:

(Parent)   Renault
(Children)   ---Megane
---Clio
---Captur
....
(Parent)   Audi
(Children)   ---A3
---A4
---A6

There should be just one column "Name", used both for children and parents nodes. The code I have so far:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from neo4j import GraphDatabase

window = Tk()

myFrame = LabelFrame(window, width=300, height=30, text="Cars viewer")
myFrame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew", pady=10, padx=10)

graph = GraphDatabase.driver(uri="bolt://localhost:7687", auth=("neo4j", "1111"))
session = graph.session()

def populate_cars_list():
    cars_tree.delete(*cars_tree.get_children())
    var_car_brands = session.run("MATCH (b:car_brand) RETURN b.name")
    for row in var_car_brands:
        for k,v in row.items():
            cars_options = v
            #display all available car brands on the tree view widget
            cars_tree.insert(parent='', index='end', values=(cars_options))
            print(cars_options)
            #for every car brand find related models
            for row_2 in cars_options:
                var_car_model = session.run("MATCH (b:car_model)-[rel_2:part_of]-(c:car_brand{name: $cars_options}) RETURN b.name", 
                                            cars_options = cars_options)
                for row_3 in var_car_model:
                    for l,m in row_3.items():
                        models_options = m
                        print(models_options)
                        cars_tree.insert(parent=cars_options, index='end', values=(models_options))
    session.close()
    
    
cars_tree = ttk.Treeview(myFrame, height=10)

cars_tree['columns'] = ("Name")

cars_tree.column("#0", width=0, stretch=NO)
cars_tree.column("Name", anchor=CENTER, width=300, minwidth=25)

cars_tree.heading("#0", text="Label", anchor=CENTER)
cars_tree.heading("Name", text="Name", anchor=CENTER)

cars_tree.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, rowspan=4, pady=5, padx=10, sticky=W)

my_btn = Button(myFrame, text='Populate list', command=populate_cars_list)
my_btn.grid(padx=10, pady=5, row=5, column=0, sticky="nsew")

window.title('Car app')
window.geometry('480x480')
window.resizable(0, 0)

window.mainloop()
```

This line doesn't work:

```
cars_tree.insert(parent=cars_options, index='end', values=(models_options))
```

The error I get:
_tkinter.TclError: Item Renault not found

As far, as I understand it is connected with iterations, in DB now I have 4 car_brands, thus I got 4 iterations and subsequently I got 4 times the same car models.

To summarize my question:

1. I need to dynamically populate the TreeView widget with children and parent nodes.
2. The parent node is extracted from DB and checked, if it has some car_models - children nodes, (in my DB for now all car brands, besides Skoda (an empty object to expect), I have at least several models), in other words, parent node should be the one from DB.
3. At the moment, I can only display the parent nodes, but not the children nodes.

I would appreciate, if you could help me to solve this problem. Thank you in advance!

Edited.
The error looks like:

```
Renault
Captur
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "<ipython-input-178-72a68666ea2a>", line 30, in populate_cars_list
    cars_tree.insert(parent=cars_options, index='end', values=(models_options))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\ttk.py", line 1369, in insert
    res = self.tk.call(self._w, "insert", parent, index, *opts)
_tkinter.TclError: Item Renault not found
```

If I comment the line:

```
cars_tree.insert(parent=cars_options, index='end', values=(models_options))
```

I can populate the TreeView with parent nodes even without providing a tuple:

[image]

Comment: At the time you get the error, what is `cars_options` and what is `models_options`. Also, `values` should be a tuple but you're passing a single value (`(x)` is the value `x`, `(x,)` is a tuple with the value `x` in it)

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, I edited my question. Even, if I put something like values= (cars_options, ), the problem is still here.

Comment: You haven't told us what `car_options` or `models_options` is right before the error.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Anyway, now it is reflected in my post.